# Function types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn the basics of Haskell and I am having a hard time understanding why the `doubleMe` type declaration causes an 'Illegal Operator' error, while `addThree` causes no error at all?

```
doubleMe :: Int -> Int -> Int
doubleMe x = x + x


addThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
addThree x y z = x + y + z
```

I appreciate any clarification.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration requires the type of each argument, and also the type of the result. Since `doubleMe` has only one argument, the declaration should be `doubleMe :: Int -> Int`.

Comment: Oh! I see. So if I was doing `doubleMe x = x + x + x + y`, the type declaration would be `doubleMe :: Int -> Int -> Int` ????

Comment: Yes, but you would have to add `y` on the left side of the `=` too; otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your doubleMe type signature specifies two parameters.

If you supply only one as is (`doubleMe x`) then the right hand side should return a function (`Int -> Int`)

Answer (score 1):

For such type questions `ghci` is a great tool. Use `:t` to ask for the type of an expression:

```
Prelude> let doubleMe x = x + x
Prelude> :t doubleMe
doubleMe :: Num a => a -> a
```

So the type is `a -> a` - you have just one argument, not two, as the other answers already pointed out.

You don't get `Int` because Haskell tries to derive the *most general* type signature. That's why you get `Num a =>` instead, which means that `doubleMe` would work for all types `a` which are instances of the `Num` type-class (where `(+)` is defined), which in turn means `doubleMe` works for `Int`, `Integer`, `Double` (at least if you don't specify a more restrictive type like `Int -> Int`)...